# How can I deploy an open source web app that hosts user data?

Tags: law, website, security, project-hosting

I'm thinking about developing an open-source web application where users can enter trips that they have done (touristic or commuting) and then view statistics and maps created from this data. From the answer to my [previous question](http://I'm%20thinking%20about%20developing%20an%20open-source%20web%20application%20where%20users%20can%20enter%20trips%20that%20they%20have%20done%20(touristic%20or%20commuting)%20and%20then%20view%20statistics%20and%20maps%20created%20from%20this%20data.) I have concluded that it would not be realistic to host this application on a server myself because I would be personally liable if there is a data breach.

What other options are there? Here's what I have thought of:

- Something like [sandstorm.io](https://sandstorm.io), if I have understood the concept correctly. It's shutting down at the end of this year though.
- Make it a mobile application (Android/iOS). The user data would then be stored on the user's phone. I really would like it to be accessible via a computer too.
- Set up a company, to make sure that I'm not personally liable (that's how I have understood the concept of a company). That would be a lot of work though.

Are there any other options?

Comment: How would making a mobile app from a web app be different from making a desktop app from a web app? (I'm envisioning Cordova/Phonegap for mobile wrapping and Electron for desktop wrapping; do I misunderstand your intended approach?)

Comment: With all respect, your question does not read like "how do I do X" but rather like "how do I do X without taking responsibility". That is more a legal question. Technically you have answered it: don't store user data - but then users cannot come back with different devices and continue on what they added with another. The link to your previous question is broken for me

Comment: @apsillers Yeah making a desktop app would also be possible, but I want it to be a modern app that anyone would like to use, so a mobile app would be much better.

Comment: It's not like I want to earn money with something without taking responsibility, instead I just want to make something available to the public that doesn't exist yet at all! I know the dilemma but I thought that there must be a different solution because certainly I'm not the only one with this problem.